# play framework production version includes source codes

Tags: playframework, production-environment

I can see source code in production version of play framework based applicaton? 
Do I need it? 
Can it be removed in production version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't need it, once the source has been compiled behind the scenes when the application first starts up in production mode. If you don't want to keep the source code on your production environment, make sure you use the precompile option

```
play precompile <appname>
```

To make sure that your application code is compiled before you distribute. The app can then be distributed without the source code. Obviously don't delete the source code unless you have it backed up in source control or other location!

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to start your application using the `-Dprecompiled=true` flag to avoid unnecessary code changes detection.

```
play start myApp -Dprecompiled=true
```

See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/releasenotes-1.1

Comment: In production mode, source code change detection is disabled. See the following URL http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/production, and note the sentence "Source modifications will not be hot reloaded"

Comment: I can tell from actual experience that even in %prod mode it will re-precompile everything if `-Dprecompiled=true` is not there. At least with Play 1.2.3.

Comment: BTW, there's no "unnecessary code changes detection" as there's no code change detection at all. It recompiles every time everything, even if the source wasn't changed. Or at least for me it definitely works like that.

Comment: well, -Dprecompiled=true definitely helped me.  It was not working without that on master branch.  NOW, the only issue is why I need to copy over app/views SINCE precompiled/templates/app/views contains all the views(it's like two copies of the same thing....why is it pointing to the wrong location)

Answer (score 1):

Only works with "play start". Don't delete the templates in app\views. All *.java files can be deleted

Comment: yeah! why is that since the directory precompiled/templates/app/views contains all the same html files...I end up with two copies of everything :(